# Spring JmsTemplate and Apache ActiveMQ, why so many connections?

Tags: spring, jms, activemq-classic, jmstemplate

I have a web application that runs text processing jobs in the background once a message is received on an ActiveMQ which is listened to by a Spring MessageListener....the problem I"m encountering is that once I process around 30 background jobs, ActiveMQ stops processing any messages, Spring message listener loses its JMS connection, and sometimes I get an error in the ActiveMQ log saying that there are too many open files.

I ran the 'lsof' (list open file) command on Linux against the ActiveMQ process and noticed that for almost each message queued/published/received by JmsTemplate, a new connection is opened. Is this normal?

here's my configuration:

```
<bean id="connectionFactory" class="org.springframework.jms.connection.CachingConnectionFactory">
    <constructor-arg ref="amqConnectionFactory" />
    <property name="exceptionListener" ref="jmsExceptionListener" />
    <property name="sessionCacheSize" value="100" />
</bean>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the PooledConnectionFactory provided by ActiveMQ, you can see full configuration [here](http://activemq.apache.org/spring-support.html#SpringSupport-WorkingwithSpring%27sJmsTemplate). Make sure you read the [JmsTemplate Gotchas](http://activemq.apache.org/jmstemplate-gotchas.html) as well.