# Does Spring JmsTemplate close connections by default?

Tags: java, spring, jms, jmstemplate

I wrote a JMS application that runs within a web service in  Glassfish (also deployed it in JBoss), I noticed that after I process several messages through a MessageListener MDP, the JMS server runs out of connections!

Tried it with both Apache ActiveMQ and Glassfish internal JMS broker (openMQ?)

Is there a way to check why this is happening? If this is the default behavior of JmsTemplate, what is my alternative for developing JMS producers and consumers the right way?

Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps you are asking the same question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4046840/spring-jmstemplate-and-apache-activemq-why-so-many-connections) differently?

Comment: Yes, I am, after investigating it, I thought it was an ActiveMQ issue first.

Answer (score 4):

The spring JMSTemplate will close and create all resources (Connections, Consumers, Producers ..) each time it receives or sends a message.
This will be a huge performance bottleneck if you are not using pooled Connections, Sessions, Consumers .... .

Having said that, yes the JMSTemplate should close your connection each time.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the connection gets closed. [See the code](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/org/springframework/jms/core/JmsTemplate.java.html) of the execute method:

```
JmsUtils.closeSession(sessionToClose);
ConnectionFactoryUtils.releaseConnection(
    conToClose, getConnectionFactory(), startConnection);
```

Comment: So why do the connections remain open on the JMS server?